# Value in column to equal other column with conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using SQL Server

The output I want: For the same values in column ID1, if there is a “null” in column ‘Value’ than make it equal to minimum(value) of that ID1.

I previously had a question relating to the following, although have still been unable to solve this!

Table 1

| ID1 | ID2 | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0.1 |
| 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 | null |
| 2 | 5 | 0.2 |
| 2 | 5 | null |
| 3 | 7 | 6 |

Output I want

| ID1 | ID2 | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0.1 |
| 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 | 0.1 |
| 2 | 5 | 0.2 |
| 2 | 5 | 0.2 |
| 3 | 7 | 6 |

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: Do  a self-join on a CTE (or nested-query) that returns the `MIN` of `ID1`.

Answer (score 3):

you can use `min()` with window function

```
select ID1, ID2,
       [Value] = coalesce(Value,
                          min(Value) over (partition by ID1))
from   yourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    WITH minimumValues AS (SELECT ID1, MIN(value) as value FROM table GROUP BY ID1)

    SELECT 
        ID1, 
        ID2, 
        COALESCE( table1.Value,  minimumValues.value) AS value
    FROM table INNER JOIN
        MinimumValues ON MinimumValues.ID1 = table.ID1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below to get the desired output -

Sample Table:

```
CREATE TABLE SampleData (
   ID1 INT,
   ID2 INT,
   Value FLOAT
);
```

Sample Data:

```
INSERT INTO SampleData 
(ID1, ID2, Value)
VALUES
   (1, 1, 0.1),
   (1, 2, 2),
   (1, 3, NULL),
   (2, 5, 0.2),
   (2, 5, NULL),
   (3, 7, 6);
```

Query:

```
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT ID1, MIN(Value) AS MinValue
   FROM SampleData
   WHERE Value IS NOT NULL
   GROUP BY ID1
)
SELECT t.ID1, t.ID2, COALESCE(t.Value, cte.MinValue) AS Value
FROM SampleData t
JOIN cte ON t.ID1 = cte.ID1
```